# Javascript - Transition

Tags: javascript, transition

I have this simple script in javascript to show and hide.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function show(obj) {

var el = document.getElementById(obj);
var bota = document.getElementById("show");

    bota.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    el.style.display = 'block';

}
</script>
```

How i do this with transitions?
Thank!

Comment: I guess you're looking for `bota.style.opacity = 0;` and CSS `#show { transition: opacity 1s; }`

Comment: Going from 'hidden' -> 'block' has no transitions, there's no interim values. You can transition 'opacity'.

Comment: Either use CSS3 transitions by adding or removing a class (fadein/fadeout) or use javascript eg: http://www.chrisbuttery.com/articles/fade-in-fade-out-with-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

You could do a fadeIn-fadeOut like this:

```js
const btnFadeToggle = document.getElementById('btnFadeToggle')
const show = document.getElementById('show')
const fade = document.getElementById('fade')

btnFadeToggle.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  fadeToggle(show)
  fadeToggle(fade)
})

const fadeToggle = (obj) => {
  obj.classList.toggle('display')
}
```

```css
.text {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
}

.text.display {
  opacity: 1
}
```

```html
<div id="show" class="text display">BOTA: This text appears and disappears on click of the button.</div>
<div id="fade" class="text">OTHER: This text appears and disappears on click of the button.</div>

<button id="btnFadeToggle">FADE TOGGLE</button>
```